# How do I filter on day & month from a date field?

Tags: 8

Hello I'm still fairly new to drupal and views,

I'm trying to create a Birthday notifier which checks "today" in a view block.
Now users can turn in their birthdays on their profile using the date field which is set as: yyyy/mm/dd.

Now the simple thing was to create a filter on the date today, but because of the yyyy field it wil not show up on today's date.

What I'd like is to filter mm/dd on today. So for example if someone's birthdate is 1993/07/03, he'd be notified as today is this persons birthday.

Is there a way to do this or to create a work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could conjure up something with the Regular expression inside the Date Filter, but that is usually not a nice path.

I haven't tried it but maybe you can do it with Contextual Filters (Under Advanced settings in the third column in Views). There is a separate Contextual filter for month, and for day:

`node.field_date (month)` and `node.field_date (day)`

Configure them with Default values `Current date`.

Comment: Yup thats it!, Sorry for the late response, managed to get an error I needed to patch and had to do some other work in the process. I'll mark your answer as the solution.